# Custom LinearLayout width - weight placing problem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view, custom-widgets

I asked another questıon and after, I continued to this problem...

Firstly My first Question: [how to Custom Button (has two TextFields) on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482364/how-to-custom-button-has-two-textfields-on-android/7501911#7501911)

I extended a class form LinearLayout, and I add two buttons in it(width- fill_parent, weight-1).
But they can't place right. If I use LinearLayout insteadof my customClass, it is working right. What Should I do??

This is my class

```
public class SplitButtonController extends LinearLayout
    implements
        OnClickListener {

// Toggle buttons
private Vector<XButton2> buttons;

// Listener
private OnClickListener listener;

public SplitButtonController(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.xbutton2, this);

}

public SplitButtonController(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    init();
}

/**
 * Initialize the toggle buttons (set images and listeners). It's
 * responsibility of the user call this method after he add a ne
 */
public void init() {
    buttons = new Vector<XButton2>();
    addLayoutButtons();
    changeButtonsImage();
    setListeners();
}
private void addLayoutButtons() {
    int n = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        View v = getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof XButton2) {
            buttons.add((XButton2) v);
        }
    }
}

private void changeButtonsImage() {
    if (buttons.size() > 1) {
        buttons.get(0)
                .setBackgroundResource(
                        com.matriksdata.bavul.R.drawable.schedule_left_button_drawable);

        for (int i = 1; i < buttons.size() - 1; i++) {
            // buttons.get(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.schedule_left_button_drawable);
        }
        buttons.get(buttons.size() - 1)
                .setBackgroundResource(
                        com.matriksdata.bavul.R.drawable.schedule_right_button_drawable);
    } else {
        // TODO:set an image with rounded sides
    }
}

private void setListeners() {
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
        buttons.get(i).setOnClickListener(this);
        buttons.get(i).setFocusable(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
        XButton2 b = buttons.get(i);
        b.setChecked(v == b);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: How should the result look like. What does the pure LinearLayout right? What's your custom layout failing to do?

Comment: result should look like, two buttons totally fill screen width and their size is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons you added to your SplitButtonController are XButton2, and in your constructor, you are inflating R.layout.xbutton2. This will cause an empty "XButton2" added to your SplitButtonController layout. You don't need to inflate anything if you want to create (or extend) a simple LinearLayout. Then your SplitButtonController code should look like following:

```
public class SplitButtonController extends LinearLayout
    implements
        OnClickListener {

// Toggle buttons
private Vector<XButton2> buttons;

// Listener
private OnClickListener listener;

public SplitButtonController(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    init();
}

/**
 * Initialize the toggle buttons (set images and listeners). It's
 * responsibility of the user call this method after he add a ne
 */
public void init() {
    buttons = new Vector<XButton2>();
    addLayoutButtons();
    changeButtonsImage();
    setListeners();
}
private void addLayoutButtons() {
    int n = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        View v = getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof XButton2) {
            buttons.add((XButton2) v);
        }
    }
}

private void changeButtonsImage() {
    if (buttons.size() > 1) {
        buttons.get(0)
                .setBackgroundResource(
                        com.matriksdata.bavul.R.drawable.schedule_left_button_drawable);

        for (int i = 1; i < buttons.size() - 1; i++) {
            // buttons.get(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.schedule_left_button_drawable);
        }
        buttons.get(buttons.size() - 1)
                .setBackgroundResource(
                        com.matriksdata.bavul.R.drawable.schedule_right_button_drawable);
    } else {
        // TODO:set an image with rounded sides
    }
}

private void setListeners() {
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
        buttons.get(i).setOnClickListener(this);
        buttons.get(i).setFocusable(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
        XButton2 b = buttons.get(i);
        b.setChecked(v == b);
    }

}

}
```